# is $\mathbb{Q} ^{|\mathbb{R}|} ‎\times‎ \{1 \}$ divisible subgroup of $ \mathbb{Q} ^{|\mathbb{R}|} ‎\times‎ \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

According to *Unit Groups of Classical Rings* by Karpilovsky, p.107 we know that:

If $F$ is a real-closed field, then $F^*‎\simeq‎ \mathbb{Q} ^{|F|} ‎\times‎ \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Now, we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is a real-closed field. So we should have $\mathbb{R}^*‎\simeq‎ \mathbb{Q} ^{|\mathbb{R}|} ‎\times‎ \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Also we know that $\mathbb{R}^*$ is not divisible but there is a divisible maximal subgroup $(\mathbb{R}^*)^+$ of $\mathbb{R}^*$. So there must exists a divisible maximal subgroup of $\mathbb{Q} ^{|\mathbb{R}|} ‎\times‎ \mathbb{Z}_2$ corresponding to $R^+$.

I think this divisible maximal subgroup is $\mathbb{Q} ^{|\mathbb{R}|} ‎\times‎ \{1 \}$, but I don't know how I should prove the divisibility of $\mathbb{Q} ^{|\mathbb{R}|} ‎\times‎ \{1 \}$.

Comment: What is $F^*$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a direct product of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, the subgroup you are considering is divisible. Given $y=(x_c)_{c\in \mathbb{R}}$ in the group and an integer $n$, define $y'=(x_c/n)_{c\in\mathbb{R}}$. Then $ny'=y$, so the divisibility condition is satisfied. Indeed, the $\mathbb{Q}^{|\mathbb{R}|}$ factor is $\mathbb{R}^+$, and the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor is $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Divisible means: for all $a\in F$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $b\in F$ such that $b^n=a$. So we should prove that if $y=(x_c)_{c\in\mathbb{R}}$, then there exists $y'$ such that $y'^n=y$. How?

Comment: @khoda I used additive notation. The operation in the group is addition, so $(y')^n=y'+y'+\cdots+y'=ny'$.

Comment: @khoda The isomorphism is a bit confusing, on the left the operation is multiplication, on the right it is addition.

Comment: But I mean by $\mathbb{R} ^*$ the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @khoda Yes, but $\mathbb{Q}^{|\mathbb{R}|}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not the multiplicative monoid because that is not a group, it is an additive group.

Comment: I agree with you. I had a mistake because I thought that the operation of right hand side is multiplication and it is wrong because it has zero element. Thank you.

Comment: @khoda No problem.